# Define a variable with the same type as a variable in a struct

Tags: c++, variables

In c++
say I have a structure defined in a header file.

```
******test.h***********
typedef struct mystruct{
    uint8_t num;
} mystruct;
```

In another header file, say myclass.h, I want to define a variable which has the same type (uint8_t) as the field "num" in mystruct.

```
******myclass.h***********
class myclass{
public:
    ??? num;
};
```

Is there a way to define such a variable? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the typeof operator?http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: @parry, That isn't standard C++.

Comment: @chris when did op say standard c++? If he/she happens to use GCC/g++ will typeof not work?

Comment: @parry, Yes, but generally, you want portable code, and `decltype` *is* standard.

Comment: If there's nothing else in `mystruct`, why don't you make `myclass::num` an instance of `mystruct`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the type in your first class, and then access it from the other class

```
******test.h***********

struct mystruct{
    typedef uint8_t num_t;
    num_t num;
};
```

And

```
******myclass.h***********
class myclass{
public:
    mystruct::num_t num;
};
```

Comment: thanks to your answer. But i would prefer not to change the struct's definition if possible due to some development reasons.

Comment: @user2565858 Then either you use C++11 extensions, or it is impossible

Answer (score 5):

Using C++11, you can use `decltype`:

```
class myotherclass
{
public:
  decltype (myclass::num) otherNum;
};
```

Without using C++11, the typical way I have done this is to take a kind of step back.  Create a `typedef`:

```
typedef uint8_t MyIntegral;
```

And then use that same type in both classes:

```
class myclass
{
public:
  MyIntegral num;
};

class motherclass 
{
pulic:
  MyIntegral othernum;
};
```

This isn't exactly what you were asking for, but if you can change the definition of `myclass` you may find this approach to be more maintainable.

Comment: @user2565858 If you want to restrict the scope where the type is defined, without using namespaces, check my answer.

Comment: thanks to your answer. But i would prefer not to change the first class's definition if possible due to some development reasons.

Comment: @Antonio:  Yep, upvoted.  In practice I would either put all of this stuff in a `namespace`, or in class scope as you have done.  I would not recommend putting it in global scope.